# change colour of legend box in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change colour of the boxes in legend for linetype in the following plot:

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:3, each = 9),
                 y = abs(rnorm(27)),
                 gr1 = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3),
                 gr2 = rep(letters[24:26], 3))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, linetype = gr1, fill = gr2)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", col = "black")
```

[image]

As the linetype legend is not clear, it would be nice to change the colour of the background. Desired output should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Trying adding `+ guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white")))`?

Comment: @Z.Lin Please post as answer.

Comment: Yes, this solves it! Thank you very much. Post it as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a list of desired changes to the `override.aes` option in `guide_legend()` to override the default aesthetic parameters for legend keys.

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, linetype = gr1, fill = gr2)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", col = "black"); p

p +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white")))

# equivalent to above
p +
  scale_linetype_discrete(guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white")))
```

[image: plot]

(I usually use this trick for transparency: e.g. scatterplot of different colours with low `alpha` for visibility of overlapped points, but high `alpha` in the colour legend to make them distinctive. In general, `override.aes` offers a great amount of versatility in controlling the legend's appearance.)